# What is the generic complexity of First Order Predicate Calculus?

Tags: computational-complexity, decidability

I suspect that it should be the same as that of the Turing machine halting problem, which wikipedia gives as GenP and attributes this result to Hamkins and Miasnikov, but I am not sure. Is the generic complexity of FOPC equal to that of TMs?  For instance, the Turing machine with two way infinite tape is apparently not known to be equivalent to the TM with one way tape.  That is one of the things that make me worry I don't really understand what is going on. If FOPC is in GenP, I would expect there to be solvers/provers for FOPC which input any well formed formula, and return true, false, or undecided in polynomial time and correctly decide most questions. Does this apply to Otter, Prover9 and similar systems?

Comment: I guess most of the people here, myself included, have no idea about generic complexity. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Wikipedia Generic-case complexity is a good start.  Three other references:
http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~downey/generic_decision.pdf    
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504351 
http://omskconf2009.oscsbras.ru/miasnikov2.pdf

Comment: A translation of this reference might be very informative:

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=semr&paperid=315&option_lang=eng

Comment: +1. I like this question very much. But it seems likely that the answer will depend on the details of the syntactic formalism. For example, insisting on normal forms or changing which logical connectives are allowed could conceivably affect the density of the set of validities. Also, adding extra predicate, function and constant symbols will affect density.